# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring, spring security, hibernate. Got a jsp page where i am trying to upload a file, and backend a i have a controller to capture and store the file uploaded. I am using tomcat. I am using spring security for login authentication. Getting the following error when i upload the file
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to ensure your request handler is able to accept a POST.  You can also configure Spring to use a MultipartResolver to aid you in getting your request parts.

Configuration of MultiPartResolver

```
@Bean(name = "mulitpartResolver")
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    if (multipartResolver == null) {
        multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Here is the request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/some/post/url")
public void postFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFileMap().get("keyForFileInFormPost");
    ...
}
```

Note, that sometimes this will not work with Spring Security.  You can look at my blog post here on using multipartrequestresolvers with spring security for help:

http://www.adamweigold.com/2012/01/using-multpartrequestresolvers-with.html

Comment: I am using the following   
`@RequestMapping(value = "/additem/fileupload.htm", method =    RequestMethod.POST)
    public String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request.getFileMap().get("keyForFileInFormPost");
    MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartRequest.getFile("file");`
Do i still need to use the mulitpartResolver bean?

Comment: i have the above code and it is throwing


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@17540bd]

Comment: Correct, you need a multipartResolver bean.  The Spring resolvers are what actually builds your method parameters.  If there is no resolver for a multipart request, you will never get one.

If the commonsmultipartresolver does not work, see my blog post.  You may need to write a custom one (they are not that hard to write).

Answer (score 0):

Just define bean "multipartResolver" in your Spring Context

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2097152"/>
    </bean>
```

And use

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/{tenantId}/getEntityInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> getEntityInfo(
        @RequestParam(value = "xml", required = false) MultipartFile xml) {
}
```